# AWS Elastic Beanstalk aws.push permission denied

Tags: git, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS (and Ubuntu, for that matter), and figured Elastic Beanstalk would be a good place to start.  I have a PHP application, in a git repository, that works fine when I test it locally or on other hosts.  Following the instructions on the getting started guide (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-get-started.html) everything works until I get to git aws.push.

I get the error:

```
fatal: cannot exec '.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push': Permission denied
fatal: While expanding alias 'aws.elasticbeanstalk.push': '.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push': Success
```

The same issue arises if I try it as root under sudo, which makes me think it's not a local problem.

I've Googled very extensively, and know little more than the obvious: "permission denied."  Is it even a local issue or an AWS authentication issue?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I'm running x64 Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: That's a permission problem. Set the permissions so you're allowed. Consult the documentation of the operating system you're using how you can set permissions of files etc.. Ask ubuntu is a good site to search (you don't need to ask that) and if you like more the style to ask and tell your story, the ubuntu forums are a great place, and there is also an ubuntu wiki that is great. Start on the ubuntu homepage, look for support and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can change permission of the file using the command `chmod` in ubuntu.

Usage: `chmod {options} filename`

The various options and details can be found in the [file permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) page.

The quick fix would be: `chmod -R 777 aws.elasticbeanstalk.push`.

Thanks